# How do I retrieve headers from WCF on the client

Tags: wcf, wcfserviceclient

I have a WCF service that is adding headers to the response.  I would like to know how to extract those headers on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195389.aspx

```
MessageHeaders.GetHeader(Of T) Method (Int32)
```

For example, within a IClientMessageInspector using the reply object, you get it like so:

```
MyObject myObj = reply.Headers.GetHeader<MyObject>(index);
```